# Error when trying to Initialize WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone have a look at my code, I don't quite follow what is the error about

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
        this.WebBrowserHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // WebBrowserHost
        // 
        this.WebBrowserHost.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.WebBrowserHost.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.WebBrowserHost.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        this.WebBrowserHost.Name = "WebBrowserHost";
        this.WebBrowserHost.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.WebBrowserHost.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // AuthorizationWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.WebBrowserHost);
        this.Name = "AuthorizationWindow";
        this.Text = "AuthorizationWindow";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

In my form I just have a `WebBrowser` control and I am having the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'

After Initialize I need ElementHost.Child like this

```
public AuthorizationWindow()
    {
        // This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowser = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
        WebBrowserHost.Child = WebBrowser;
        WebBrowser.Navigating += WebBrowser_Navigating;
        WebBrowser.LoadCompleted += WebBrowser_LoadCompleted;
        _authorization = new AuthorizationState();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the line

```
this.WebBrowserHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
```

to

```
this.WebBrowserHost = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

?

Comment: You are creating a object from the class System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and instantiating it with a System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost object. That won't work. I cannot figure out what you are trying to do? Just edit the first line of code in the first code section you have posted.